# MongoDB: Query For and Return List of Embedded Documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have several `solutions`, which in term may hold several `projects`. I modeled this relationship by `embedding` the projects in the solution document, e.g.

```
[{
    _id: "1",
    solutionTitle:  "Some Test Solution",        
    projects: [
      {
         _id: "12",
         type: "Java",
         title: "Test Project"
      },
      {
         _id: "13",
         type: "Misc",
         title: "Test Project"
      }
    ]
 },
 {
    _id: "2",
    solutionTitle:  "A Different Solution",  
    projects: [
      {
         _id: "21",
         type: "Java",
         title: "Another Java Project"
      }
    ]
 }]
```

Now I want to `select all projects` of a special type, e.g. `Java`. I tried the following `query` with aggregation:

```
db.Solutions.aggregate ( 
    { "$unwind": "$projects" }, 
    { "$match": {"projects.type": "Java" } }, 
    { "$project": {"projects" : 1, "_id": 0, "solutionTitle": 0 } } 
)
```

This works fine but the result doesn't look like what I expected. I get

```
{
    projects: {
        _id: "12",
        type: "Java",
        title: "Test Project"
    },
    projects: {
        _id: "21",
        type: "Java",
        title: "Another Java Project"
    }
}
```

How can I get the result to be a list of projects, e.g.

```
[
    { _id: "12", type: "Java", title: "Test Project" }
    ...
]
```

I checked [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785707/mongodb-aggregate-embedded-document-values) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268568/mongodb-query-to-return-only-embedded-document), but they do not really cover what I need. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to be in an array, you'll need to add them to an array:

```
db.Solutions.aggregate ([
    { "$unwind": "$projects" }, 
    { "$match": {"projects.type": "Java" } }, 
    { "$group": {"_id": null, "projects": { "$push": "$projects" } } }
])
```

In light of your comments below, it seems what you really want is to return the project subdocuments as if they were the documents you were searching. In which case you should `$project` your project values explicitly:

```
db.Solutions.aggregate ([
    { "$unwind": "$projects" }, 
    { "$match": {"projects.type": "Java" } }, 
    { "$project": {"_id": "$projects._id", "type": "$projects.type", "title": "$projects.title" } }
])
```

Comment: Can I get it without the object `wrapper` as well? Just a list of projects directly? Now I get an object with a property `projects`, which is a list.

Comment: I have updated my answer to satisfy that requirement.

Comment: Thx! Is there a way to take all fields automatically? This is rather tiresome if you have a lot of columns.

Comment: I don't believe there is, but I'd be happy to be proved wrong on that.